# Formal Languages

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, language

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

Emmy prefers when you are formal.

- Tua’s fathseir
  ▢▢▢◯▢ ◯▢◯▢▢
- They jotú in cheress
  ▢▢◯▢▢▢◯
- Duge where some were Bistarin
  ▢▢▢▢▢ ◯▢▢◯▢▢
- Home of NJ's Irrace and Ity clubs
  ▢▢▢◯◯▢▢▢▢
- Nertuness of athles and actors
  ▢◯▢▢▢ ▢▢◯▢▢▢
- Tutin Gatlin, Ares, Ihena, e.g.
  ◯▢▢▢▢▢▢◯

Please describe Emmy.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We *are* being too informal -

> in six different languages, in fact!
>
>  Each of these clues contains a second-person pronoun in some language; it needs to be changed to the *formal* version of that pronoun. (So French "tu" becomes "vous"; Spanish "tú" becomes "usted"...)
>
>  Additionally, each clue also has a second-person conjugation of the word for "to be" in that language - we need to change *that* to the formal form as well.

The full list is:

> [Italian: "tu sei" → "Lei è"]
>  **Tu**a’s fath**sei**r
>  → **Lei**a's fath**e**r
>
>  [Spanish: "tú eres" → "usted es"]
>  They jo**tú** in ch**eres**s
>  → They jo**usted** in ch**es**s
>
>  [German: "Du bist" → "Sie sind"]
>  **Du**ge where some were **Bist**arin
>  → **Sie**ge where some were **Sind**arin
>
>  [Czech: "ty jsi" → "vy jste"]
>  Home of N**J's I**rrace and I**ty** clubs
>  → Home of N**J's Te**rrace and I**vy** clubs
>
>  [French: "tu es" → "vous êtes"]
>  Ner**tu**ness of athl**es** and actors
>  → Ner**vous**ness of athl**etes** and actors
>
>  [Latvian: "tu esi" → "jūs esat"]
>  **Tu**tin Gatlin, Ar**es, I**hena, e.g.
>  → **Jus**tin Gatlin, Ar**es, At**hena, e.g.

Now the clues can be answered!

> The clue answers are:
>
>  Leia's father: `DAR(T)H (V)A(D)ER`
>  They jousted in chess: `KN(I)GHT(S)`
>  Siege where some were Sindarin: `MINAS (T)IR(I)TH`
>  Home of NJ's Terrace and Ivy clubs: `PRI(N)(C)ETON`
>  Nervousness of athletes and actors: `S(T)AGE FR(I)GHT`
>  Justin Gatlin, Ares, Athena, e.g.: `(O)LYMPIA(N)`
>
>  And the circled letters spell **TV DISTINCTION** - [the "formal/informal" contrast that this puzzle is about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction), and also an appropriate description of an Emmy award!

Comment: Ah, well done - I've been struggling to spot the Czech one and couldn't quite get it in time! Great answer, well written up.